# How do you show that the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ of $z(x,y)$ is equal to the inverse of the partial derivative of $x$ with respect to $z$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For a general function $z(x,y)$, writing the derivatives as ratios of finite-differences, how do you show that:

[image]
is true? Please push me in the right direction of what to do. I know how to take partial derivatives and what finite differences are, but I don't understand this question. How do you even start? What are the steps involved? Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: what is that $y$ subscript ?

Comment: You need to say what you mean.  You wrote $z(x,y)$, so I know what $\partial z/\partial x$ means.  But then you write $\partial x/\partial z$.   What does that mean?  How is $x$ written as a function of two variables?  That can be done in more than one way, which may yield different values for $\partial x/\partial z$.

Comment: The y subscript indicates y is kept constant, Ahmad Bazzi. And, I don't know what that means either, that is why I'm confused, GEdgar.

Comment: I believe GEdgar was pointing out the following: Visually, from a defined function $z = f(x,y)$ and it's graph, the relationship $x = g(y,z)$, (whose graph is just a "rotation" of the original graph if you like), may or may not be a function. I.e. a single $(y,z)$ input many output to many $x$'s. Therefore to make it a true function, you have to pick a "branch of the surface", which is why he referred to many possible $x = g(y,z)$'s

Comment: DWade64, thank you for your comment. I understand what you're saying. The problem however doesn't give any other parameters to solving it other than what I stated, and I just need some kind of first step or steps to providing the answer, as I don't know how to start. Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Because of your first line, thinking of $\partial z$ and $\partial x$ as numbers, the problem makes me think that you have to prove $4/7$ is $(1/(7/4))$, which is true as proved in algebra/arithmetic. However, I need a better understanding of the inverse function theorem to fully grasp the topic. Basically, the proof that you need is going to be exactly the same as the proof in single variable calculus (look up the proof of the theorem between the derivative of a single variable function and the derivative of its inverse). You have to think of $z = f(x,y)$ as a single variable function. Then

Comment: assuming that the surface patch is invertible (inverse function theorem), $x = g(y.z)$ will exist. Think of this as a single variable function. Then copy over the proof that I mentioned verbatim. I'd try that